# C# OpenGL: How to translate a triangle

Tags: c#, opengl, 2d

I am trying to translate/move a triangle 0.3 to the right. When I run the code below, it moves the triangle, but part of it is cut off, like it is in a set box (shown in images below).

Code to move and draw the triangle:

```
  Gl.glPushMatrix();
  Gl.glColor3f(c.R, c.G, c.B);
  Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);
  Gl.glVertex2f(0.5f+x, 1.0f+y);
  Gl.glVertex2f(0.0f+x, 0.0f+y);
  Gl.glVertex2f(1.0f+x, 0.0f+y);
  Gl.glEnd();
  Gl.glFlush();
  Gl.glPopMatrix();
```

**x is 0.3f, y is 0** I tried `glTranslatef()`, but that did the same thing.
The triangle at 0, 0, 0
[image]
The triangle at 0.3f, 0, 0
[image]

Comment: Looks like it's being clipped by your viewport?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you configure your rendering viewport/display window?